# AttributeError Module 'asyncio.coroutines' has no attribute '_DEBUG' Error

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

I recently wanted to create a discord bot which fetch the stats of a player in the Rainbow Six Siege game and display them, I found an API with a documentary on how to use it and as it seems it uses python 3.7

The code I am trying to execute is the code below:

```
import asyncio
import r6statsapi

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

client = r6statsapi.Client("TOKEN")
players = loop.run_until_complete(
    client.get_generic_stats('NotASm8rf.-', r6statsAPI.Platform.uplay)
)
```

Every time I try to run this code I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\R6S Greece Bot\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import r6statsapi
  File "C:\Users\win\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\r6statsapi\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client import Client as Client
  File "C:\Users\win\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\r6statsapi\client.py", line 4, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "C:\Users\win\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import BaseConnector as BaseConnector
  File "C:\Users\win\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . import hdrs, http, payload
  File "C:\Users\win\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\http.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .http_parser import HeadersParser as HeadersParser
  File "C:\Users\win\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\http_parser.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .helpers import NO_EXTENSIONS, BaseTimerContext
  File "C:\Users\win\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 100, in <module>
    old_debug = coroutines._DEBUG  # type: ignore
AttributeError: module 'asyncio.coroutines' has no attribute '_DEBUG'
```

I tried searching but couldn't find anything, any help?

I tried searching the web but couldn't find something here.

Comment: looks like you on python 3.12. Did you try lower versions of python?